# Standard Report Column in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

What's the difference between a Standard Report Column and one that is set to Display as   Text (escape special characters)?.How can you ensure that the data displayed in a Standard Report Column is safe?

Answer (score 2):

A standard report column does not escape special characters.  So if you have data in the column that contains HTML like `<script>alert('hello');</script>` then a standard report column will cause a browser alert to appear saying "hello", whereas the display as text columns would just display the text `<script>alert('hello');</script>`.

You should only use s Standard Report Column when you **need** the column to render some HTML (rather than display it as text) - for example, to display an image in a report, or an input field etc.  In those cases you need to ensure that you are in control of the data that is being displayed in that column - which you typically will be.  If any data that appears in the column is entered into the database by users then you need to ensure it does not contain anything special - e.g. use `htf.escape()` function to make it safe.

Comment: Thanks Tony Andrews..for your valuable time.